# How to fix Xcode refusing to install swift packages

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Packages in Xcode are all of sudden not fetching anymore and when I'm trying add different package from github (local swift packages on my own server work fine) it's stuck at `Preparing to authenticate...` and shows `An unknown error occured` after a while.

[image]

I tried deleting derived data, cleaned the project.
I'd appreciate any suggestions. :(